# Swift – "weak self" optional binding allowing avoid Retain Cycles

Tags: swift

It seems a little odd, but the following block of code you can often meet inside a completion handlers' bodies for methods of `URLSessionWebSocketTask` class of `Foundation` framework.

Here's an example:

```
func send(data: Data) {

    let dataMessage = URLSessionWebSocketTask.Message.data(data)

    webSocketTask.send(dataMessage) { [weak self] error in

        guard let self = self else { return }

        if let error = error {

            self.delegate?.onError(connection: self, error: error)
        }
    }
}
```

What does this capture binding mean exactly?

Comment: You seem to understand that the aim of `[weak self]` is to avoid retain cycles, so what are you asking exactly? By "capture binding" do you mean the _capture_ list or the optional _binding_ statement?

Comment: I'm asking: what does this expression mean in simple words `{ [weak self] error in guard let self = self else { return } }` and what will be if I don't use it. Why `self` is used?

Comment: `DispatchQueue.main.async` is a pretty bad example because all `DispatchQueue` closures don't cause retain cycles. Many tutorials suggest `[weak self]` or `[unowned self]` in a `DispatchQueue` context but that's wrong.

Comment: @vadian Thank you, I've corrected it.

Comment: [This article](https://stablekernel.com/how-to-prevent-memory-leaks-in-swift-closures/) offers a good explanation, along with other info that might be helpful

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In an `@escaping` closure like `send` `self` is captured as strong reference by default.

So `self` holds a strong reference to `send` and `send` holds a strong reference to `self` (in the `delegate` line). That's called a retain cycle and causes a memory leak because both the closure and the instance representing `self` will never be deallocated after the closure is executed.

To avoid a retain cycle you have to capture `self` as `weak` (it becomes optional) or `unowned`. It makes sure that `self` will/can be deallocated when the closure goes away. You don't need the capture group in non-escaping closures like the `DispatchQueue` closures.

The `guard` statement checks if `self` is still alive. In other cases you can easily use optional chaining like `self?.delegate?.doSomething()`

Answer (score 1):

By default a closure will capture a scope properties with strong reference. This means that as long as there are "strong" references to an object, it will not be deallocated. To avoid that, one can set a weak reference to `self` which is captured by the closure.

Analogy:

**strong reference:**

You send your son to the bakery to buy a bread and you give him a list of things to do after he will come back. After few minutes you get a call from your friend which ask you to go out with him, but because your son asked you to stay at home you can't go out.

**weak reference (weak self):**
You send your son to the bakery to buy a bread and you give him a list of things to do after he will come back. Because you are not sure that you will be at home when he will be back, you say: Son, If I will be not present at home after you will be back then do nothing (guard let self = self else { return })